# The method does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net

I call a function in my aspx file

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CustName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# GetCustName((Int32?)Eval("custId")) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have created a function GetCustName in code behind, however the error log window still shows

```
The name GetCustName dose not exist in current context.
```

Can any one tell me what's the problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the methods accessibility modifier is restricting access to it in the ASPX page, `GetCustName` needs to be either `Protected` or `Public`

Comment: Thanks, I have been try both Protected and Public, but still not working.

Comment: It may also need to be static/Friend

Comment: please check your inherits attribute in the @page directive

Comment: I was able to make it work after making the method 'static'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace following line

```
<%# GetCustName((Int32?)Eval("custId")) %>
```

with

```
<%= GetCustName((Int32?)Eval("custId")) %>
```

Answer (score -2):

clean solution and get latest version and rebuild it~